# Chrome Extension avoid reloading popup

Tags: caching, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome Extension that has the popup browser action, and I've realized that every time a user clicks the extension icon, it reloads the script. If I have an AJAX call in the extension, how can I cache or save the data, such that I do not have to make the same call every time the user opens the extension popup?

Comment: Save the state to `localStorage` or in the background page.